# When I run my ASP.NET Core MVC solution from another user it does not connect to the SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created a simple ASP.NET Core MVC application in Visual Studio. I also created a database using EF Core code first approach. The database uses Windows authentication.

The connection string I used was

```
Server=(local)\\sqlexpress;Database=LibraryEmployeeDB;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

I am supposed to send this project to my professor but when I tried to run the project from a different user on my computer it doesn’t work because I can’t connect to the database with the other user.

I tried to change to Windows and SQL Server authentication and create a new user and add that to the connection string but that didn’t work either. I would be so grateful for any tips on how to solve this problem so that my professor can run the project as it is supposed to. Thank you!

Comment: How will your professor get access to your database? What kind of database is that?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly stating the username and password that you created in the connection string? `Server=(local)\\sqlexpress;Database=LibraryEmployeeDB;UserId=username;Password=password;`?

Comment: You haven't posted any error messages. "Doesn't work" doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Where you store the SQL Express LocalDB? By default, access to the instance of LocalDB is limited to its owner. The data contained in the LocalDB is protected by file system access to the database files. If user database files are stored in a shared location, the database can be opened by anyone with file system access to that location. If the database files are in a protected location, such as the users data folder, only that user and the administrators with access the database. The LocalDB files can only be opened by one instance of LocalDB at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You should run init command to create the database :
"Update-Database" in the Package manager console in the Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Your Connection String shulde be like this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
"ConnStr": "Data Source=(local)\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=LibraryEmployeeDB;Integrated Security=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;Trusted_Connection=false;User ID=yourUsername;Password=yourPassword;"
```

}
and in Startup.cs you have to use this section:

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<YourContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnStr")));
      //and other things
    }
```